# JCR Node imported as nt:file when using content-package-maven-plugin

Tags: aem

I created an OSGI config JCR node in XML within my Adobe CQ project under /apps/myproject/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-MYPROJECT.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root
    xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
    xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.level="Trace"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.file="logs/myproject.log"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.file.number="5"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.file.size="5MB"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern="\{0,date,HH:mm:ss.SSS} *{4}* {3} {5}"
    org.apache.sling.commons.log.names="[com.mycompany.myproject]" />
```

Problem is that when it gets imported into the JCR, it is showing up as an `nt:file` instead of what it should be according to its `jcr:primaryType` so that it look like this in CRXDE

[image: incorrect import as nt:file]

when it should look like this

[image: expected import as sling:OsgiConfig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my XML markup starts EXACTLY as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root
    xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
    ...
```

What I had done originally was to create a new xml file and put in my config. There are 2 other ways I know to create nodes

1. By doing it in CRXDE and then using vault to export
2. By doing it in Eclipse using the AEM developer tools (Eclipse plugin for Apache Sling)

In the case of a vault export, the XML starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" ...
```

and in the case of the plugin, it starts like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root 
    xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
    ...
```

but wait, you can't see it here, the plugin actually adds a friggin blank space right after `jcr:root`.

So whatever XML parser is acting on these XML files to create nodes in the JRC, it behaves oddly if there is no space right after the root node name. I'm on Windows, using Maven 3.2.3, using version 0.0.20 of content-package-maven-plugin, and AEM 5.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your filter definition of the content-package-maven-plugin. If your filter root is set to

```
<filter>
<root>
/apps/myproject/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-MYPROJECT.xml
</root>
</filter>
```

instead of

```
<filter>
<root>
/apps/myproject/config/org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config-MYPROJECT
</root>
</filter>
```

then it will likely just put the file into your repository instead of creating the configuration node.
The latter one without .xml file extension is correct.

Comment: I think you mean <filter root="..." /> because the other one where root is an element is invalid. And either way it does not work.

Comment: Depends where you define the filter statement. The maven plugin is fine with <filter><root> ... if you do it directly inside the configuration section.

Comment: Nope, neither in filter.xml or in plugin config. But I did find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jcr:mixinTypes="[]" type as a property to your logger. So Your configuration will be like :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
        jcr:mixinTypes="[]"
        jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.level="Trace"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.file="logs/myproject.log"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.file.number="5"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.file.size="5MB"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern="\{0,date,HH:mm:ss.SSS} *{4}* {3} {5}"
        org.apache.sling.commons.log.names="[com.mycompany.myproject]" />
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nope didn't work. Where did you get that idea from? Your XML markup did lead me to see something that turned out to be the solution.